# adding event handler to applicationCache leads to compile error

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, application-cache

If I add this line to my code

```
if (window.applicationCache) {
    applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready',
        window.location.reload);
}
```

I get this weird error:

```
/home/matej/archiv/2014/projekty/zalmy/zalmy.ts(58,22): error TS2082:
 Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target:
    Could not apply type '"downloading"' to argument 1 which is
    of type 'string'.
/home/matej/archiv/2014/projekty/zalmy/zalmy.ts(58,22): error TS2087:
    Could not select overload for 'call' expression.
make: *** [zalmy.js] Error 1
```

What's going on? Is it a bug in tsc? (using the latest typescript 0.9.5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it up in a function :

```
if (window.applicationCache) {
    applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', () => {
        window.location.reload();
    });
}
```

Reason is that the argument for event listener `(ev:Event)` is different from the optional argument for `reload` (boolean)

Comment: You are obviously right, but that makes me feel there are severe limitations with strict-type languages. One has to do inelegant nonsenses like this. Hmm.

Comment: @mcepl Without TS you were actually calling location.reload with true (the event object is truthy) and invalidating your cache. Was that intentional?